# permanent address

Tags: client, address

How can I set a permanent address wallets to send and receive?
How can I find out in advance which address the coins will be sent?
 We have a community in MLM that pays membership of the coins.
Upon registration, it is necessary to specify the address of BTC wallets. Payment system detects on the basis of registered wallet in the system. Now we have a problem because sending address changed every time..so that it shows in every transaction a different address.
You can help solve this problem?
Thank you in advance.
mark

Comment: It's confusing what you mean by "a permanent address wallets".  Can you clarify?  Also, it's good to use your question as the title, rather than a topic like "permanent address".  Being more clear will help you get better answers.

Comment: It seems to me that you're asking "How can I set my wallet to always reuse the same address?", but you're not telling us what wallet software you are using. Also, your explanation why you would want to do this seems very confused. It seems to me that there are better ways to do it, than address re-use.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking how to identify which payment came from who, then you want a new receiving address to be generated for each new member.

With an HD wallet you will have control of all address balances despite the address changes

https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/hd-protocol